# Regex matches in regexpal but not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regex that will work for validating URLs.  I found this guy:

```
^(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?$
```

Which worked pretty well when I [tested it using regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5E%28http%7Cftp%7Chttps%29://%5B%5Cw-%5D%2b%28%5C.%5B%5Cw-%5D%2b%29%2b%28%5B%5Cw.,@?%5E=%25&:/~%2b#-%5D%2a%5B%5Cw@?%5E=%25&/~%2b#-%5D%29?%24&input=http://s3.amazonaws.com/SomeShow/Podcasts/HouroneofWhatever234.mp3), but when I actually plug it into my javascript it fails to match.  [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tJhFN/)

I am testing against this URL:

`http://s3.amazonaws.com/SomeShow/Podcasts/HouroneofWhatever234.mp3`

Can anyone see why it would match in regexpal, but not when I try to use it in my javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex literal:

```
/^(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+...$/
```

(you also have to escape the slashes to prevent the them to be interpreted as ending regex terminal symbol)

If you use a string, you have to escape every backslash, because the backslash is the escape characters in strings as well.

```
new RegExp("^(http|ftp|https)://[\\w-]+...$")
```

In your current expression, `"[\w-]+"` will turn to `[w]+` because `\w` is not a valid escape sequence in strings.

---

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression

Comment: And escape every forward slash.

Comment: because I will get an unexpected token error otherwise? http://jsfiddle.net/tJhFN/2/

Comment: Yeah, fixed... it's a bit late here ;)